# Page not found: Custom search form with a custom search page

Tags: url-rewriting, search, 404-error

Let me show you an example of what I'm trying to achieve. On [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/) website when you click the `search BBC` button on the navbar it brings you to a search page (https://www.bbc.co.uk/search). When you put something in the search field (say apple) and hit enter the URL becomes (https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=apple&page=1) and this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve ( &page=1 is not required). So what I did is -

#1 first created a new page using pages -> add new option and titled it `search` and changed the default template to the search template `search.php`

2# I also have `searchform.php` serving as my custom search form template. Here is the code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="/search" id="search-form">
    <div class="search-field-wrapper">
        <label for="search-field" class="visually-hidden"><?php _ex( 'Search for:', 'label' );?></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="search" name="s" id="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ) ;?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ;?>">
        <span class="search-icon-wrapper"><i class="feather search-icon" data-feather="search"></i></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I'm searching for something the URL becomes `http://localhost/search/?s=hello` and getting `404 not found`. So, how can I get it to work like the [site](https://www.bbc.co.uk/search) I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `template_redirect` action to add **/search/** to your search URL's. Check out the code below:

```
function my_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/search/' ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_change_search_url' );
```